# What is appropriate angle for camera to recognize coins?

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to do a coins recognition project where a camera will take a picture of couple of coins then recognize them by value, sum them up and output the amount of money. I was thinking of recognizing values just by looking up at their size, (the bigger the coin the bigger the value) but problem I can think of is, what if picture is taken from different angle or camera has different distance from coins than usual? How to solve it or is there any alternative way for that? I have no previous experience in image processing, I want to learn as I go.

Comment: Take [this example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html) as a demo on what those classic image-processing tools can do for you (at least for preprocessing). I would not go after size-metrics, but some kind of object-detection (might already be solved in the example) followerd by object-classification (classic ML tools).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not so easy if you haven't any experience... however camera angle is not a problem if you can understand the basics of the imaging process and the geometry behind it: by using a calibrated camera you can retrieve an omography of the surface where the coin will be (assuming they are on a table).

When you try to recognize your coins, what you can try to do practically is using ellipse fitting algorithms or a hough circle transform to find the circles on the bird-eye view of the table obtained from original image using the omography.

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion, what valleymanbs has said is basically correct. Just add a few things that I feel it is important to you.
You need to understand the following things

1. Calibration a camera. -> you get intrinsic parameters such as focal length and principle point, etc and also extrinsic parameters such as camera rotation and translation, so you can rectify the image later.
2. Recify image. -> The image recification will modify the image so that you will get a view that . To this purpose, I suggest you put your camera right above the table on which you will place your coins. The distance between the camera and the table shall be large which implies that the resolution of your camera shall be also high enough.
3. As long as you understand the principle of camera calibration and image rectification and get the images of your coins you can do image segmentation using either eclipse algorithm or hough transform, just to get the arrounding circle of your coins.
4. Then you can do some image processing such as binarization or erosion, whatever it is needed to calculate the area of the circle.
5. However, personally I won't take just one feature such as the size of the coin to determin the value of the coin since some coins with different values can have really similar size. Therefore, I would recommend you another technic which is called the classifier. You can add features like color or even texture. Then in you case, I think you could apply the SVM: support vector machine to classify your coins into the right class.

   I understand that you have no experince with the image processing. But there is no short cut to your solution. I would suggest you take your time to understand the framework of my proposal and the underlying reason of each step. Have fun. :)
   Hope this can be helpful to you.

Comment: great clarification of my answer for newbies, thank you yirui. I would just add to what you correctly said that after some sort of preprocessing, which you also suggest in point 4, you could still search for circles (using i.e. OpenCV's blob detector), select the ROIs around the detected blobs and then run the classifier just on these ROIs. The double check you suggest, not only on size, is of course desirable, but fitting blobs is easy and very fast... you could also keep that check and robustify it with the classifier.